# Setting the properties for ScrollView in LinearLayout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

How do I set the properties for the following ScrollView's present in both LinearLayout so that they are scrollable. I'm programmatically adding views to both LinearLayouts.

```
    <ScrollView  > 
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLeft"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="#88FF0000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView > 
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearRight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:background="#8800FF00"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This isn't your actually layout, I'm assuming? You should add the complete layout. And can you be a bit more clear on what you mean?

Comment: So you basically want 2 scroll views side by side,with individual scroll?

Comment: Please provide complete Xml :)

Comment: @Droidekas yea... I want to scroll 2 views side by side with individual scroll... and it is my complete XML... I add the rest via code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally sorted out my problem and here is my code. Sorry for not being clear with my question.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#88FF0000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearRight"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#8800FF00"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```